# Date Converting in Loop in R

Tags: r, datetime, as.date

Hello again stackoverflow. I'm encountering problems in my R code again in converting columns of dates imported from Excel in a double loop in R. The following code is what I wrote in order to convert the data (starting from column 11 to column 19 of the whole data set, with column length of 17).

```
for (m in  11:19) {
  for (i in 1:17) {
    if (is.POSIXct(data_agg[[i,m]])) {
      data_01 <-  as.Date(data_agg[[i,m]])
      data_agg[[i,m]] <- data_01
    }
    else if (grepl("^[[:digit:]]+$",data_agg[[i,m]])) {
      data_02 <-  as.Date(as.numeric(data_agg[[i,m]]),origin="1899-12-30")
      data_agg[[i,m]] <- data_02
    }
  }
}
```

There are two types of data I want to convert to correct date format. One is "POSIXct" and one is "character". For the ones are of "POSIXct" type, the original data looks like the following (take the 11th column as an example):

```
data_agg[[11]]
 [1] "2018-03-16 UTC" "2018-03-16 UTC" "2018-03-16 UTC" "2018-03-16 UTC" "2018-03-16 UTC" "2018-03-16 UTC" "2018-03-16 UTC" "2018-03-16 UTC" "2018-03-12 UTC"
[10] "2017-07-20 UTC" "2018-06-07 UTC" "2018-03-15 UTC" "2018-03-06 UTC" "2017-10-19 UTC" NA               NA               NA   

str(data_agg[[11]])
     POSIXct[1:17], format: "2018-03-16" "2018-03-16" "2018-03-16" "2018-03-16" "2018-03-16" "2018-03-16" "2018-03-16" "2018-03-16" "2018-03-12" "2017-07-20" "2018-06-07" ...
```

In order to convert to the correct format, I use `as.Date` and store it in a dummy variable `data_01` and reassign the original value with that dummy variable.

For the ones that are of "character"type, the original data looks like the following (take the 12th column of the data set as an example):

```
data_agg[[12]]
 [1] "N/A"   "N/A"   "N/A"   "N/A"   "N/A"   "N/A"   "N/A"   "N/A"   "Yes"   "Yes"   "N/A"   NA      NA      "43045" NA      NA      NA 

str(data_agg[[12]])
 chr [1:17] "N/A" "N/A" "N/A" "N/A" "N/A" "N/A" "N/A" "N/A" "Yes" "Yes" "N/A" NA NA "43045" NA NA NA
```

Since I'm only interested in the number "43045" and convert it back to the date format, I used

```
(grepl("^[[:digit:]]+$",data_agg[[i,m]]))
```

to see if there is any number contained in the character string, and if it is, convert it back to the normal date format represented in the following code:

```
else if (grepl("^[[:digit:]]+$",data_agg[[i,m]])) {
      data_02 <-  as.Date(as.numeric(data_agg[[i,m]]),origin="1899-12-30")
      data_agg[[i,m]] <- data_02
```

So, I ran the nested loop, but the result is far from what I expected. The 11th column in the data set became the following:

```
data_agg[[11]]
 [1] "1970-01-01 04:53:26 UTC" "1970-01-01 04:53:26 UTC" "1970-01-01 04:53:26 UTC" "1970-01-01 04:53:26 UTC" "1970-01-01 04:53:26 UTC" "1970-01-01 04:53:26 UTC"
 [7] "1970-01-01 04:53:26 UTC" "1970-01-01 04:53:26 UTC" "1970-01-01 04:53:22 UTC" "1970-01-01 04:49:27 UTC" "1970-01-01 04:54:49 UTC" "1970-01-01 04:53:25 UTC"
[13] "1970-01-01 04:53:16 UTC" "1970-01-01 04:50:58 UTC" NA                        NA                        NA
```

It should've given me the result of

```
"2018-03-16" "2018-03-16" "2018-03-16" "2018-03-16" "2018-03-16" "2018-03-16" "2018-03-16" "2018-03-16" "2018-03-12"
[10] "2017-07-20" "2018-06-07" "2018-03-15" "2018-03-06" "2017-10-19" NA               NA               NA
```

And the 12th column of the data set became the following:

```
data_agg[[12]]
 [1] "N/A"   "N/A"   "N/A"   "N/A"   "N/A"   "N/A"   "N/A"   "N/A"   "Yes"   "Yes"   "N/A"   NA      NA      "17476" NA      NA      NA
```

It should've given me the result of:

```
 [1] "N/A"   "N/A"   "N/A"   "N/A"   "N/A"   "N/A"   "N/A"   "N/A"   "Yes"   "Yes"   "N/A"   NA      NA      "2017-11-06" NA      NA      NA
```

What am I missing here? Much appreciated with your help!

Comment: Am I correct that "2018-03-16 UTC" is a string? You can find this by using str() or class(). If this is a string then `is.POSIXct(data_agg[[i,m]])` is always false. So you are never performing this part of the if/else statement.

Comment: FYI: Lubridate has a function to convert that YYYY-MM-DD to a date and which returns an NA and a Warning() if it fails. `lubridate::ymd("2018-03-16 UTC")`. This also works for vector inputs (entire columns at once).

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for the reply! It turned out that "2018-03-16 UTC" is "POSIXct" "POSIXt" before I ran the loop.

Comment: Just a note that I solved the issue by googling. I tried different ways for formatting the dataframe. Instead of formatting each object in the vector, I chose to format each vector in the data frame using lubridate::ymd as suggested by Adam Sampson for 11th Column. For the 12th column, since date formatting the whole column would result in warning, I used grepl to find those objects needed to be formatted and reassigned with the format I wanted.